# Unable to send Bulk email using whenever gems in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, whenever

I have used whenever gems,where i have schedule more than 500 mails to execute at a particular  time,but its not going.But if i send 15 or 20 email then it goes.I am getting the following in my output file of whenever.

```html
rake aborted!
Net::SMTPServerBusy: 452 4.5.3 Error: too many recipients
/home/indiba3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.8/gems/mail-2.6.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:114:in `block in deliver!'
/home/indiba3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.8/gems/mail-2.6.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:113:in `deliver!'
/home/indiba3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.8/gems/mail-2.6.4/lib/mail/message.rb:253:in `deliver!'
/home/indiba3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.8/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:77:in `deliver_now!'
/home/indiba3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.8/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:95:in `deliver!'
/home/indiba3/hrms/lib/tasks/email_tasks.rake:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/indiba3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.8/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/indiba3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.8/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/indiba3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.8/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => task_namespace:birthday_invitation_mail
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

So how may i slove this error and let the email to be sent to 500 person and if any email is wrong i may get the output in another log file........so pls help...........??

Answer (score 0):

Fetch users in batches and then try to send mails.

## mailer

```
def birthday_email
  date = Date.today 
    Employee.where("status = ? AND strftime('%d/%m', date_of_birth) = ?", "Active" , date.strftime('%d/%m')).where("age > 21").find_in_batches do |group|
      sleep(5)
      group.each { |emp| mail(to: emp.email, subject: 'Birthday Wishes')  }
    end
  
end
```

## rake

```
EmployeeMailer.birthday_email.deliver!
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138535/discussion-on-answer-by-puneet18-unable-to-send-bulk-email-using-whenever-gems-i).